# CollectionDataContract with the extra property

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xml-parsing

I am working with the list in the WCF. I want to pass the list between the client and server with the one extra property inside it.

**Needed Output**

```
<NumbersList>
    <Count>2</Count> //Extra property to parse
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Number>2</Number>
</NumbersList>
```

So I follow the tutorial at this link: http://www.borismod.net/2009/04/wcf-collectiondatacontract-and.html

And I wrote the below code to achieve that.

```
[MessageContract]
public class RequestResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "NumbersList")]
    public NumbersList NumbersList;
}

[DataContract]
public class NumbersList
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Number Number { get; set; }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Number")]
public class Number : Collection<int>
{        
}
```

So it give me the **output** like this:

```
<NumbersList>
    <Count>2</Count>
    <Number>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Number>2</Number>
    </Number>
</NumbersList>
```

If I put the `Count` property decorated with the `DataMember` directly inside the `CollectionDataContract` than the however WCF omit that property.

**One more try:**

```
[MessageContract]
public class RequestResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "NumbersList")]
    public Number NumbersList;
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Number")]
public class Number : Collection<int>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Count { get; set; } // This will be omited...
}
```

Than it can be give the **output** like this:

```
<NumbersList>
    <Number>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Number>2</Number>
    </Number>
</NumbersList>
```

Can any one help me to get the **output** like this:

**Needed Output**

```
<NumbersList>
    <Count>2</Count>
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Number>2</Number>
</NumbersList>
```

Comment: From what I know, it is not possible.

Comment: @selami, It may be possible, Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing the R&D and study and posting my query at the asp.net forum I get the solution.

In my case `CollectionDataContract` would not help me, For do that I have to use the `XmlSerializerFormat`

So I rewrite my code like this:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Messanger
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NumbersList")]
    public NumbersList NumbersList;
}

[DataContract]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "NumbersList")]
public class NumbersList
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Number")]
    public List<int> Number { get; set; }
}
```

and It will generate the XML for me like this:

```
<NumbersList>
    <Count>2</Count> //Extra property to parse
    <Number>1</Number>
    <Number>2</Number>
</NumbersList>
```

Here is the link of the forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12ceeae4-0284-4a3b-a913-e69811f41b81/collectiondatacontract-with-the-extra-property?forum=wcf